# JS - Await inside forEach

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have an array over I call an API with its value. But I notice that the calling of the API are not in order to the array content. This is my code:

```
points = [1, 2, 3, 4]
points.forEach(async point => {
  console.log(point);
  const res = await fetch(`${URL}/${point}`, {headers: { ... }})
  console.log(res);
});
```

It's look like that it doesn't wait the return of the `fetch`.
I tried with `Promise.all()` but the problem persist. This is the output of my code:

```
1
2
3
4
Response {} <-- on point 1
Response {} <-- on point 5
Response {} <-- on point 4
Response {} <-- on point 2
Response {} <-- on point 3
```

Comment: _"It's look like that it doesn't wait the return of the fetch"_ - this is why you shouldn't use `forEach` with `async-await`. Use the `for-of` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `forEach` I guess.

I would rather use a `for of` loop instead like

```js
points = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for(const point of points){
  console.log(point);
  const res = await fetch(`${URL}/${point}`, {headers: { ... }})
  console.log(res);
};
```